# How to convert custom string to json using python?

Tags: python, json, string

I have a string like following: `'a:b# c:d# e:f#'` how to convert this into json like = `{'a':'b','c':'d','e':'f'}` using python. Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: This is not JSON, that is just a dictionnary

Comment: You could use regular expressions (module re) to collect data in a dict and generate json with the respective module.

Comment: Each value is ended with a #, right? Then you can split along the #s, then split each substring along the :, put everything into a hash map and use an out-of-box JSON serializer to turn it into well-formed JSON.

Comment: You may think about accepting an answer to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20findall#re.findall) to get all the pairs of matching values and then cast that list to a `dict`:

```
import re

s = 'a:b# c:d# e:f#'

d = dict(re.findall(r'(\w+):(\w+)#', s))
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}
```

To convert that to a JSON string, use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json%20dumps#json.dumps):

```
import json
print(json.dumps(d))
```

Output:

```
{"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `#`, then split on space to get parts, then split on `:` to pair the mapping

```
s = 'a:b# c:d# e:f#'     
res = dict(v.split(':') for v in s.replace("#", "").split())
print(res)  # {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'a:b# c:d# e:f#'

items = str.split("#")

result = {item.split(":")[0]:item.split(":")[1] for item in items[:-1]}

print(result)
{'a': 'b', ' c': 'd', ' e': 'f'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import json

str = 'a:b# c:d# e:f#'        # input string
kv = re.compile("(\w):(\w)")  # prepare regular expression
l = kv.findall(str)           # find all <key>:<value> pairs
d = dict(l)                   # convert list to dict
j = json.dumps(d)             # generate JSON
print( d )
```

prints

```
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the fastest/shortest solution.
However I think it might be the one, that's easiest to be understood by a beginner.

You can then shorten / optimize the code if needed.

Your question consists of two parts.

1.) How to convert a string, that is in a specific format into a python data structure

2.) How to convert a python data structure into json

```
import json

def my_parse(data_str):
    result = {}
    entries = data_str.split('#')  # split input by '#'
    for entry in entries:
        entry = entry.strip()  # remove leading and trailing white space
        if entry:  #
            key, val = entry.split(":")
            # cleanup key and val. (strip off spaces) perhaps you don't need this
            key = key.strip()
            val = val.strip()
            result[key] = val  # add to our dict

    return result

example_data = 'a:b# c:d# e:f#'
rslt_dict = my_parse(example_data)
print("result dict is", rslt_dict)


# convert to json string.
json_str = json.dumps(rslt_dict)

# or directly write json to file
with(open("myjsonfile.json", "w")) as fout:
    json.dump(rslt_dict, fout)
```